# How can I use two select statements in one view

Tags: sql, sql-server

This first select statement gives me a result which i want.

```
  SELECT   
       b.num, 
       DATEPART(yyyy, b.dateofstatus) AS yearofinsert, 
       b.yearbegin, 
       ac.code,
       ac.store,    
  FROM table1 b LEFT JOIN class ac 
  ON b.idclass = ac.id LEFT JOIN admin.dbo.DboObj s 
  ON s.id = b.idobj LEFT JOIN
```

But when I include this another one statement it gives me an error "problem near WITH", i know that problem is temporary table can't be included in view, but how can i pass that problem, is there any other solution instead of using tmp table?

```
;WITH tmp(idsubj,DataItem, subject) AS
(
    SELECT
        idsubj,
        LEFT(subject, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), subject + CHAR(10)) - 1),
        STUFF(subject, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), subject + CHAR(10)), '')
    FROM table1 WHERE idobj = 2
    UNION all

    SELECT
        idsubj,
        LEFT(subject, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), subject + CHAR(10)) - 1),
        STUFF(subject, 1, CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), subject + CHAR(10)), '')
    FROM tmp
    WHERE
        subject > ''
        
)


SELECT
    idsubj,
    DataItem
INTO #a FROM tmp
ORDER BY idsubj
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)


SELECT replace(#a.DataItem,'  ',' ') as allbooks, #a.idsubj
FROM #a 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON #a.idsubj=table1.idsubj
LEFT JOIN table2 po ON #a.idsubj = po.idsubj
ORDER BY idsubj
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: A `VIEW` cannot return multiple datasets. A `VIEW` is a  virtual table defined by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Showing some example records to `table1` and `table2` and the example output that you want from your view will help a lot. A View is a single query with a single result set, so while we can easily combine multiple requests into a single query it is not clear if this is will have the output that you are expecting.

Comment: @SqlKnightKing can you provide some clarity so we can help you out?